# detect touchstart event for multi touch action on android 2.3 default browser

Tags: javascript, html, multi-touch, android-2.3-gingerbread

*How to detect touchstart event for multi touch action in android 2.3 browsers?*

Recently I had a chance to look into this issue as part of my project. Adding the findings and workaround as answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**
*Detect touchstart event for multi touch action on android 2.3 browsers*

**Findings:**
In multi touch supported browsers, a multi touch event object will contain an array "touches", which will have all the touch points.
But in Android 2.3 default browsers it contains only single touch point for multi touch action and it will trigger multiple touch start event consecutively.
We can see this consecutive touch start events with only one touch point are triggered instead one touchstart with multiple touch points by logging the events.

**Workaround:**
Touchstart event can be identified bby storing the touch events in an array.
And whenever a new event is occurred chekc the previous event also. If the consecutive events are touchstart, we can assume it is multi touch.

Please see the references below:
Google discussion on touch event issue:

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11909

For testing the multi touch support in browsers

- http://scripty2.com/demos/touch/touchspector/
- http://www.paulirish.com/demo/multi
- https://rawgit.com/borismus/MagicTouch/master/index.html
- https://cdn.rawgit.com/muhammedbasil/6d49a884f6ca315614be/raw/5aed46a31d46638b15fbb0a34366346e67d0738a/index.html